# Automapper - Ignore mapping with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I'm using automapper and I would like to know if it's possible to ignore a mapping of a field when that's null.

That's my code:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.BusinessGroup_Id, 
           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (int)src.BusinessGroup))
```

- `src.BusinessGroup type = "enum"`
- `dest.BusinessGroup_Id = int`

The objective it's to ingore that Mapping if src.BusinessGroup = null.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think [`NullSubstitute`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Null-substitution) option will do the trick

```
.ForMember(d => d.BusinessGroup_Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => (int?)s.BusinessGroup));
.ForMember(d => d.BusinessGroup_Id, o => o.NullSubstitute(0));
```

BTW you can write your conditions in mapping action:

```
.ForMember(d => d.BusinessGroup_Id,
           o => o.MapFrom(s => s.BusinessGroup == null ? 0 : (int)s.BusinessGroup));
```

*UPDATE* if you cannot assign some default value to your property, you can just ignore it and map only not nulls:

```
.ForMember(d => d.BusinessGroup_Id, o => o.Ignore())
.AfterMap((s, d) =>
    {
        if (s.BusinessGroup != null)
            d.BusinessGroup_Id = (int)s.BusinessGroup;
    });
```

Comment: Hi lazyberezovsky, thank's for your fast response! I can't set 0 to BusinessGroup_Id because that's a foreingKey on DB