# AutoMapper Writing Null On Target Field When Source Field Does Not Exist

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following objects:

```
public class DomainStudent {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AdvisorId { get; set; }
}

public class ApiStudent {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long AdvisorName { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the following mapping:

```
ApiStudent api = new ApiStudent();
api.Id = 123;
api.AdvisorName = "Homer Simpson";

DomainStudent existing = service.load(api.Id); // 123
// at this point existing.AdvisorId = 555

existing = Mapper.Map<ApiStudent, DomainStudent>(api);
// at this point existing.AdvisorId = null
```

How can I configure AutoMapper such that when the property `AdvisorId` is missing from the source object, so that it does not get overwritten to null?

Comment: Could you please correct the code first? AdvisorName is declared as long but "Homer Simpson" is assigned to it.

Comment: Does this question: [Merge two objects to produce third using AutoMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463183/merge-two-objects-to-produce-third-using-automapper) help you at all?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194072/automapper-ignore-mapping-with-condition

Comment: This isn't quite what I want. ... what I want is to NOT overwrite a field to NULL if it didn't have a matching field on the source object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change the Map() call to:

```
Mapper.Map(api, existing);
```

and then configure the mapping to:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<ApiStudent, DomainStudent>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AdvisorId, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: The second code snippet should be `Mapper.CreateMap<ApiStudent, DomainStudent>()...` instead of `CreateMap<ApiStudent, DomainStudent>()...` since `CreateMap` is a static method.

Comment: @RyanGates Fixed. I copied from my AutoMapper Profile classes and forgot to change it.